# Logic App/JavaScript - Assigning a random password to each JSON object

Tags: javascript, azure-logic-apps

I have below input that I'm passing to my Logic App:

**Input:**

```
{
   "value":[
      {
         "employeeId":"123",
         "mailNickname":"testUser1"
      },
      {
         "employeeId":"456",
         "mailNickname":"testUser2"
      },
      {
         "employeeId":"789",
         "mailNickname":"testUser3"
      }
   ]
}
```

Then, I have below steps to generate a random password using Inline JavaScript Code, and then Compose action to create a new field called "Password" and assign JavaScript result to it.
This seems to be working fine without any error but I'd like to run Inline JavaScript step for each object and assign new passwords to each object.

[image]

**Desired output:**

```
{
   "value":[
      {
         "Employee ID":"123",
         "Username":"testUser1",
         "Password":"<random_password1>"
      },
      {
         "Employee ID":"456",
         "Username":"testUser2",
         "Password":"<random_password2>"
      },
      {
         "Employee ID":"789",
         "Username":"testUser3",
         "Password":"<random_password3>"
      }
   ]
}
```

Can someone advise please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run js code inside For Each block between value and Compose